# How to mock IExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync() method in EFcore

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, moq

I write the following code in my project. It is the public method `CreateInstallmentDiscountAsync` which call other private methods. I used to cover it with Unit-tests, but I have got a problem. In `CreateDiscountAsync` method I create an `IExecutionStrategy` object and call extension method `ExecuteAsync(this IExecutionStrategy strategy, Func<Task> operation)` with delegate as parameter.

**My goal** is to find a way to cover the code that is passed in this delegate. I mean I would like to check if the state of `InstallmentPaymentTask task` object is changed after call `await CompleteDiscountCreatingAsync(task, cancellationToken);`. So I guess that I need to mock `IExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync` method, I have no idea how to make this method be called with the delegate I am passing in my code. I try to write this unit test, but I didn’t manage to make a mock in such a way as to pass the necessary delegate to it

This is the method I need to cover.

```
    public async Task CreateInstallmentDiscountAsync
    (
        InstallmentPaymentTask task,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default
    )
    {
        try
        {
            await CreateDiscountAsync(task, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            task.SetDiscountCreatedError(ex.Message);
            _movedRepository.Update(task);
            await _movedRepository.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
            _loggingService.Log(LoggingLevel.Error, ex);
        }
    }

    private async Task<Order> CreateDiscountAsync
    (
        InstallmentPaymentTask task,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default
    )
    {
        var createDiscountCommand =
            BankInstallmentDiscountCommand.Create(task.OrderId, task.TotalAmount, task.AmountWithoutCommission);
        
        Order order = null;
        var strategy = _movedUnitOfWork.CreateExecutionStrategy();
        await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
        {
            await using var transaction = await _movedUnitOfWork.OpenTransactionAsync(cancellationToken);
            order = await _mediator.Send(createDiscountCommand, cancellationToken);
            await CompleteDiscountCreatingAsync(task, cancellationToken);
            await transaction.CommitAsync(cancellationToken);
        });

        return order;
    }

    private async Task CompleteDiscountCreatingAsync
    (
        InstallmentPaymentTask task,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default
    )
    {
        task.CompleteDiscountCreating();
        _movedRepository.Update(task);
        await _movedRepository.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
```

this ** is not correct ** Unit test I try to write.

```
    [UnitTest]
    public async Task CreateInstallmentDiscount_Success_DiscountIsCreated()
    {
        var message = new InstallmentPaymentTaskMessage
        {
            CustomerEmail = "lol",
            OrderId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            PaymentDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
            AmountWithoutCommission = 9600,
            TotalAmount = 10000,
        };

        var task = InstallmentPaymentTask.Create(message);

        var order = OrderFactory.CreateOrder();

        var movedRepositoryMock = new Mock<IMovedRepository>();
        movedRepositoryMock
            .Setup(_ => _.Update(task));
        movedRepositoryMock
            .Setup(_ => _.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()));

        var transactionMock = new Mock<IDbContextTransaction>();
        transactionMock
            .Setup(_ => _.CommitAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()));
        
        var movedUnitOfWorkMock = new Mock<IMovedUnitOfWork>();
        movedUnitOfWorkMock
            .Setup(_ => _.OpenTransactionAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(transactionMock.Object);
        
        var executionStrategyMock = new Mock<IExecutionStrategy>();
        
        executionStrategyMock
            .Setup(strategy => strategy.ExecuteAsync(
                It.IsAny<object>(),
                It.IsAny<Func<DbContext, object, CancellationToken, Task<object>>>(),
                It.IsAny<Func<DbContext, object, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult<object>>>>(),
                It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
            ))
            .ReturnsAsync(new ExecutionResult<object>(default, false));
        
        movedUnitOfWorkMock
            .Setup(_ => _.CreateExecutionStrategy())
            .Returns(executionStrategyMock.Object);

        var mediatorMock = new Mock<IMediator>();
        mediatorMock
            .Setup(_ => _.Send(It.IsAny<BankInstallmentDiscountCommand>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(order);

        var rabbitMqServiceMock = new Mock<IRabbitMqService>();
        rabbitMqServiceMock
            .Setup(_ => _.GetInstallmentPaymentTaskCreateQueue())
            .Returns(new Queue { Name = "lol" });
        rabbitMqServiceMock
            .Setup(_ => _.SendMessageAsync(It.IsAny<Queue>(), It.IsAny<string>()));

        var service = new InstallmentPaymentService(movedRepositoryMock.Object, mediatorMock.Object,
            movedUnitOfWorkMock.Object, rabbitMqServiceMock.Object, null);

        await service.CreateInstallmentDiscountAsync(task);

        task.Status.Should().Be(InstallmentPaymentTaskStatus.DiscountCreated);
        task.ErrorMessage.Should().BeNull();
        rabbitMqServiceMock.Verify(_ => _.SendMessageAsync(It.IsAny<Queue>(), It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Never);
        movedUnitOfWorkMock.Verify(_ => _.OpenTransactionAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
        transactionMock.Verify(_ => _.CommitAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
        movedRepositoryMock.Verify(_ => _.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
    }
```